# Adding content to an existing SharePoint solution file (WSP)

Tags: solution-package, packaging

I want to add a list, library, and custom web part to an existing `.WSP` file. I cracked open the existing `.WSP` file (renamed it to `.cab` and extracted it) and it contains list instance templates, template modules, and web templates. Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Was that WSP a saved site template, or a solution built in Visual Studio?

Comment: It was a saved site template.

Answer (score 2):

The only method I can think of, which is Alex's, seems quite messy in my opinion, and might break current sites that use any templates built from that WSP.

My suggestion is to start a new solution in visual studio, and have it supplement your WSP.

That way, you have complete control over the solution as you have the source right there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. A solution package is a simple CAB archive with files and several instruction files. You need to modify solution's manifest and DDF file with instructions to makecab.exe. See the details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543741.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to Unpack and Repack it again you can download and use this simple tool from here:
[extract or unpack wsp files and vise versa](http://www.itnerd.ir/post/2013/07/24/extract-or-unpack-wsp-files-and-vise-versa)
download it from end of post by the name of: "WSPCompression.zip" and password of zip archive is: www.itnerd.ir